# FSTAB not loading properly

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs

So today I updated my `/etc/fstab` to mount few NFS shares to my NAS and while I can type in the terminal and successfully mount them, `fstab` doesn't seem to fully execute after restart.

I am running Mint, but I'm not sure if it matters.

This is my `fstab` file.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=0fad24fa-b1e5-48aa-b738-a06f214207b9 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3715-6F02  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0


#3/13/2018 NFS shares to Synology
10.0.0.5:/volume1/homes/alex2wr    /media/alex2wr   nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
10.0.0.5:/volume1/homes/alex2wr/Downloads    ~/Downloads   nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
10.0.0.5:/volume1/video    ~/Videos   nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
10.0.0.5:/volume1/photo    ~/Pictures   nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

Comment: Do you have anything that could help you and us to understand this problem in syslog or output of journalctl -xe ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the problem is the relative paths used. If you run in console:

```
mount -t nfs 10.0.0.5:/volume1/video ~/Videos
```

Works because the `~` refers to the user's home folder. When you restart the system the `~` does not, so you have to write the absolute path, eg:

```
 10.0.0.5:/volume1/video /home/<username>/Videos
```

Comment: Moreover, `~` is expanded by the shell. I am pretty sure shell is not involved when processing `fstab`.